# jquery ui selectable add/remove class on selected/unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

Using jquery ui selectable , How it is possible to add a custom class on `selected/selecting` event and removing it on `unselected/unselecting`

I know we can style selection using CSS:`.ui-selected{}` but this deosnt help if I want to add custom class like `ui-state-focus`.

For Try, you can use my Fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/CjT3r/2/.
In this example i want to add/remove `ui-state-focus` class on selected/unselected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy with using JavaScript for that, you can do it by handling the events:

- `selecting`
- `selected`
- `unselecting`
- `unselected`

To add/remove your custom classes.

Say you have `classA` for "selecting" and `classB` for "selected".  Your selectable should be created like this:

```
$(".ui-splitselect-list").selectable({
    cancel: ".ui-splitselect-item .ui-splitselect-handle-drag",
    selecting: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.selecting).addClass('classA');
    },
    unselecting: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.unselecting).removeClass('classA');
    },
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.selected).addClass('classB');
    },
    unselected: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.unselected).removeClass('classB');
    }
});
```

Applied to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CjT3r/4/

Answer (score 0):

You an add jquery scripts as a function like what we do in javascript.
use a onclick event
for example you want to add or remove class from the div below

```
<div id="divExample" class="normalstyle" onclick="ChangeClass(this)">example text</div>
```

you acn write a jquery function for this

```
function ChangeClass(divid){
$(divid).removeClass('normalStyle');
$(divid).addClass('selectedStyle');
}
```

Advantage of doing like this is you can use this function for other elements too